# Query Combining Records Based on Columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am creating an access query to give a live view of the quantities of parts in a database, however I am not sure where to start with it. Lets say I have the following table, there are many more columns but these are the important three:

```
| PartNumber | Description   | Quantity |
| 12345      | a part        | 4        |
| 12345      | a part        | 3        |
| 54321      | another part  | 1        |
| 24513      | an extra part | 6        |
```

I would like the query to produce;

```
| PartNumber | Description   | Quantity |
| 12345      | a part        | 7        |
| 54321      | another part  | 1        |
| 24513      | an extra part | 6        |
```

So it then tells me how many of each part there is in the database.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic `GROUP BY` aggregation query should work here:

```
SELECT PartNumber, Description, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY PartNumber, Description;
```